# Why can't the compiler figure out (_ >: T) => (_ <: V[_ <: U]) <: T => V[U] for V[+_]?

Tags: scala, existential-type

So I was playing around a bit, trying to write something on existentials and variance, and I came across this interesting piece of code.

```
final case class Box[+T](val value: T) {
  def >>=[U](f: T => Box[U]) = f(value)
  def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this >>= f
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
Variance.scala:3: no type parameters for method >>=: (f: T => Box[U])Box[U] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (_$1 => _$2)
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : _$1 => _$2 where type _$2 <: Box[_ <: U], type _$1 >: T
 required: T => Box[?U]
  def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this >>= f
                                                                   ^
Variance.scala:3: type mismatch;
 found   : _$1 => _$2 where type _$2 <: Box[_ <: U], type _$1 >: T
 required: T => Box[U]
  def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this >>= f
                                                                       ^
```

which I find strange, as isn't `(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])` a subtype of `T => Box[U]`? Because `Function1` is contravariant in the first type parameter, this is a subtype of `T => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])`. Since `Function1` is covariant in the result type, this is a subtype of `T => Box[_ <: U]`, and since `Box` is covariant in its parameter, isn't the entire thing a subtype of `T => Box[U]`?

Strangely, changing the code to

```
// This change is not required ;)
type Box[T] = `What A Category Theorist Calls "The Identity Monad" And What Everyone Else Calls "A Box"`[T]
final case class `What A Category Theorist Calls "The Identity Monad" And What Everyone Else Calls "A Box"`[+T](val value: T) {
  def >>=[U](f: T => Box[U]) = f(value)
  def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this >>= (f: T => Box[U])
}
```

with a type ascription to "hint" the compiler that `f: T => Box[U]` makes it compile. Since there's no implicit conversion or variable declaration here shouldn't this have made no difference?

The other way I found of getting this to compile is writing

```
def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this.>>=[U](f)
```

This makes me believe that the issue is less with the compiler having a hard time getting that `(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U]) <: T => Box[U]` and more with it not being able to infer the type parameter of `>>=`, which seems to be what the error message is alluding to.

(Using Scala 2.12.1 (with sbt, if that changes anything))

Answer (score 0):

```
final case class Box[+T](val value: T) {
  def >>=[U](f: T => Box[U]) = f(value)
  def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this >>= f
}
```

`flatMap` retrun type is `Box[U]`, but to use `this >>= f`.

So `>>=` will automatic  to change to `f` type `(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])`.

So `Box[(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])]` not match `Box[U]`.

I think you can change like that:
`def flatMap[U](f: (_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])): Box[U] = this >>=[U] f`

Comment: I know how to make the code work; I'm asking *why* it needs to be fixed, because `_ <: Box[_ <: U]` *should* match `Box[U]`. I am aware that adding `[U]` to `>>=` makes it compile.

Comment: reason is `Box[(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])]` not match `Box[U]`

Comment: Can you explain where you get `Box[(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])]`?

Comment: `>>=` will automatic to get parameters `f` type `(_ >: T) => (_ <: Box[_ <: U])` to become `>>=` generic `U` in frist.